# Converting Byte Array to String (NXC)

Tags: string, arrays, nxt, nxc

Is there a way to show a byte array on the NXTscreen (using NXC)?

I've tried like this:

```
unsigned char Data[];
string Result = ByteArrayToStr(Data[0]);
TextOut(0, 0, Result);
```

But it gives me a `File Error! -1`.

If this isn't possible, how can I watch the value of `Data[0]` during the program?

Comment: You should pass only `Data`, not `Data[0]`. So, it's `ByteArrayToStr(Data)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the byte array in hexadecimal format, you can do this:

```
byte buf[];
unsigned int buf_len = ArrayLen(buf);

string szOut = "";
string szTmp = "00";

// Convert to hexadecimal string.
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < buf_len; ++i)
{
    sprintf(szTmp, "%02X", buf[i]);

    szOut += szTmp;
}

// Display on screen.
WordWrapOut(szOut,
            0, 63,
            NULL, WORD_WRAP_WRAP_BY_CHAR,
            DRAW_OPT_CLEAR_WHOLE_SCREEN);
```

You can find [`WordWrapOut()` here](https://bitbucket.org/muntoo/nxtfilemanager/src/3fb2d919f2f8/WordWrap.nxc).

---

If you simply want to convert it to ASCII:

```
unsigned char Data[];
string Result = ByteArrayToStr(Data);
TextOut(0, 0, Result);
```

---

If you only wish to display one character:

```
unsigned char Data[];
string Result = FlattenVar(Data[0]);
TextOut(0, 0, Result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `byte`. `byte` is an `unsigned char` in NXC.

**P.S.** There is a heavily-under-development debugger in BricxCC (I assume you're on windows). Look [here](https://sourceforge.net/apps/phpbb/mindboards/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=838&hilit=debugger#p7714).

**EDIT:** The code compiles and runs, but does not do anything.